# Parsley.js - Validate optional input for only numbers

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, parsley.js

I have a form that has one optional input and 3 required input fields. For the optional input I have the below markup:

```
<input type="number" placeholder="0" min="0" max="20000" step="100" data-parsley-validation-threshold="1" data-parsley-trigger="keyup">
```

This does not fire the validation if I have type in letters or any other characters. It does validate for min and max values. If I put required attribute it does seem to work but I don't want that. I also tried defining a pattern as below:

```
data-parsley-pattern="^[0-9]*$"
```

None of them seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: To clarify, you want the field to be optional (so, the field can be empty). However, if the user sets some value you want it to be integer. Is that it ?

Comment: @milz Yes that is correct

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `data-parsley-type="digits"`. Notice the use of `type="text"` instead of `number`.

This works if you only want to allow digits (not floats).

```
<input type="text" placeholder="0" min="0" max="20000" step="100" 
    data-parsley-validation-threshold="1" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" 
    data-parsley-type="digits" />
```

If you want floats, you can use `data-parsley-type='number'`:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="0" min="0" max="20000" step="100" 
    data-parsley-validation-threshold="1" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" 
    data-parsley-type="number" />
```

Comment: This seems to work but what if I need to accept floating values as well? like 10.5?

Comment: @user3312508 I've updated the answer to allow floats.

Comment: This apparently fails HTML validation cause I have type text and then min max attributes. Also doesnt show the increment/decrement functions. For eg: http://cl.ly/image/2P0k3H3W0S2r

Any remedy? Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Uhm... I'll have to take a look at the regex that Parsley is using. I'll let you know when I find a solution.

Comment: @user3312508 It seems that's a Parsley Bug. If you take a look at Parsley.js source code, around `line 1681` is where it will add `number` or `integer` constraint. So far so good and the both use Regex. The Regex validation is performed on `line 758`. Now the issue is that the regex is only performed if you already have an integer / float. If you have a string there's no `Regex.test()`. I couldn't find the cause to this, but you might want to [file a issue on GitHub](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues).

Comment: As a workaround, you might want to use Parlsey with a Numeric Validation Plugin ([like this](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/)). Nevertheless, it would be better to fix it directly in Parsley source code.

Comment: Note there is a typo in the first line of the above answer. `parsley` is spelt incorrectly. Just mentioning in case anyone else copied and didn't immediately notice (like me)!

Comment: @James Fixed it. Thanks.